# Elastic search : delete operation with query

Tags: elasticsearch

when I execute this function it doesn't consider the query parameter
{"match": {type: "local"}} it deletes all the items.
any idea?
Thanks in advance.

```
delete: function (callback) {


        client.indices.delete({
            index: 'twitter',

            body: {
                query: {"match": {type: "local"}}
            }
        }, function (err, res) {
            if (err)
                console.error(err.message);
            callback();
        });


},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [client.indices.delete](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-indices-delete) API will always delete the whole index you specified, so any body params won't make difference in the request.
What you are looking for is the [client.deleteByQuery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-deletebyquery) API method, that allows you to specify a query against which you want to perform the deletion of the elements inside an index.

```
  client.deleteByQuery({
      index: 'twitter',
      body: {
        query: {
          {"match": {type: "local"}}
        }
      }
    }, function (err, res) {
         if (err)
            console.error(err.message);
          callback();
  });
```

Comment: TypeError: client.indices.deleteByQuery is not a function

thank you! T

Comment: it's not client.indices.deleteByQuery but client.deleteByQuery, index is specified inside the arguments object